# Output base64 encoded image data to body background?

Tags: php

I have a function that can output base64 encode encoded image data to a tag.
The following works:

```
echo '<img src="'.$base64.'">';
```

But if I try the following with same prepared data, it no longer works.

```
echo '<body background="'.$base64.'">';
```

Any solutions for this to work in  tag directly?

EDIT: I wish to note that I was unable to manipulate the background attributes via Javascript after using the following method in the accepted solution:

```
echo '<body style="background: url(data:image/png;base64,'.$base64.')">';
```

However I fixed this by echoing the image-data with php directly to the style instead inside style tags:

```
<style>
body {
<?php
  echo 'background-image: url('.$base64.');' . "\n";
  echo 'background-size: 100% 100%;' . "\n";
?>
}
</style>
```

I am not sure why is behaves differently.

Comment: Your syntax appears to be wrong in the frost cade. It should be ` 
<img src="data:image/png;base64,xxxxxx...">`. See http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/

Comment: ohh you also missing `style=""`

Comment: Actually that data:image/png is included in the $base64 data. sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<body style="background: url(data:image/png;base64,'.$base64.')">';
```

Replace `image/png` with `image/jpeg` if your base64 data represents a jpg image.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Sorry for not making clear, I added the data:image/png within the $base64 data (adding it accordingly after detecting the image format/mime type. echo '<body style="background: url('.$base64.')">';

Comment: By the way do I have to clear cache or free the memory somehow to make sure the photodata gets updated. Now the data does not change/update even if I edit or replace the source photo file.

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen No, I dont think this data will get cached by the browser. Can you confirm the data is really different? You can also go into devtools and disable cache, then reload.

Comment: Well I resized an image for example but it still keeps reloading the same old data. Same happends if I replace the image completely.

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen Maybe your whole HTML page is being cached. Does the background change when you clear cache?

Comment: The issue vanished now after began testing on a server via FTP, was running PHP locally and it was acting weirdly. Works now, no idea why it did that : )

Comment: Just remember that base64 encoding adds about 30% to the amount of data and can't be cached if it's in a dynamic page, which leads to a lot of unnecessary bandwidth consumption. There's a reason why people don't do this a lot.

Comment: @jhilgeman That's true. But you know what's weird. Go to google shopping search, and check their preview images. They are all base64. I wonder why...

Comment: @ManuelOtto - Several reasons. An inline image reduces the amount of connections since the browser doesn't have to establish a separate server connection to download the image. If you don't have a lot of repeat requests for the same product image, there's little benefit to a browser cache. Finally, since a single shopping page could have dozens of SMALL product photos, it's far more efficient/faster to deliver the page by bundling it all into a single, large page and free up a dozen connections for more unique shoppers. I'm just saying it's USUALLY not a good idea for most pages.